# How to obtain monotonic effect of ordered factor predictor in lme4 package

Tags: r, lme4, mixed-models, multilevel-analysis

I want to obtain a monotonic effect for an ordinal predictor with the function `lmer()` from the package lme4. My reference is the estimate that can be obtained with `mo()` in the brms package (a more developed review of monotonic effects for ordinal predictors can be found here https://psyarxiv.com/9qkhj/).

Below a reprex with the desired estimate (leaving aside the different statistical approach behind both packages) in `m1`, and what happens by default (`m2`) when an ordered factor is used `lmer()`

```r
library(brms)
library(lme4)
sleepstudy$Days <- factor(sleepstudy$Days, ordered = T)
m1 <- brm(Reaction ~ mo(Days) + (1 | Subject), data = sleepstudy, chains = 2)
#> Compiling Stan program...

summary(m1)
#>  Family: gaussian 
#>   Links: mu = identity; sigma = identity 
#> Formula: Reaction ~ mo(Days) + (1 | Subject) 
#>    Data: sleepstudy (Number of observations: 180) 
#> Samples: 2 chains, each with iter = 2000; warmup = 1000; thin = 1;
#>          total post-warmup samples = 2000
#> 
#> Group-Level Effects: 
#> ~Subject (Number of levels: 18) 
#>               Estimate Est.Error l-95% CI u-95% CI Rhat Bulk_ESS Tail_ESS
#> sd(Intercept)    39.73      7.85    27.73    58.76 1.01      538      751
#> 
#> Population-Level Effects: 
#>           Estimate Est.Error l-95% CI u-95% CI Rhat Bulk_ESS Tail_ESS
#> Intercept   257.11     10.87   235.14   277.72 1.00      468      774
#> moDays       10.12      1.01     8.16    12.09 1.00     1603     1315
#> 
#> Simplex Parameters: 
#>            Estimate Est.Error l-95% CI u-95% CI Rhat Bulk_ESS Tail_ESS
#> moDays1[1]     0.07      0.06     0.00     0.20 1.00     1343      747
#> moDays1[2]     0.07      0.05     0.00     0.20 1.00     1275      524
#> moDays1[3]     0.13      0.07     0.01     0.29 1.00     1337      591
#> moDays1[4]     0.10      0.07     0.00     0.28 1.00     1600      850
#> moDays1[5]     0.16      0.09     0.01     0.34 1.00     1285      658
#> moDays1[6]     0.09      0.06     0.00     0.24 1.00     1543      840
#> moDays1[7]     0.09      0.07     0.00     0.25 1.00     1534      992
#> moDays1[8]     0.16      0.08     0.02     0.32 1.00     1897      906
#> moDays1[9]     0.13      0.08     0.01     0.31 1.00     1839      936
#> 
#> Family Specific Parameters: 
#>       Estimate Est.Error l-95% CI u-95% CI Rhat Bulk_ESS Tail_ESS
#> sigma    31.25      1.81    27.93    35.19 1.00     1726     1341
#> 
#> Samples were drawn using sampling(NUTS). For each parameter, Bulk_ESS
#> and Tail_ESS are effective sample size measures, and Rhat is the potential
#> scale reduction factor on split chains (at convergence, Rhat = 1).

m2 <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (1 | Subject), data = sleepstudy)
summary(m2)
#> Linear mixed model fit by REML ['lmerMod']
#> Formula: Reaction ~ Days + (1 | Subject)
#>    Data: sleepstudy
#> 
#> REML criterion at convergence: 1731.8
#> 
#> Scaled residuals: 
#>     Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
#> -3.3473 -0.5293  0.0317  0.5328  4.2570 
#> 
#> Random effects:
#>  Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
#>  Subject  (Intercept) 1375.5   37.09   
#>  Residual              987.6   31.43   
#> Number of obs: 180, groups:  Subject, 18
#> 
#> Fixed effects:
#>             Estimate Std. Error t value
#> (Intercept)  298.508      9.050  32.985
#> Days.L        95.074      7.407  12.835
#> Days.Q         7.744      7.407   1.045
#> Days.C        -0.705      7.407  -0.095
#> Days^4         5.889      7.407   0.795
#> Days^5         1.754      7.407   0.237
#> Days^6        -6.036      7.407  -0.815
#> Days^7        -1.695      7.407  -0.229
#> Days^8        -4.161      7.407  -0.562
#> Days^9         6.435      7.407   0.869
#> 
#> Correlation of Fixed Effects:
#>        (Intr) Days.L Days.Q Days.C Days^4 Days^5 Days^6 Days^7 Days^8
#> Days.L 0.000                                                         
#> Days.Q 0.000  0.000                                                  
#> Days.C 0.000  0.000  0.000                                           
#> Days^4 0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000                                    
#> Days^5 0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000                             
#> Days^6 0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000                      
#> Days^7 0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000               
#> Days^8 0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000        
#> Days^9 0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000
```

How could an equivalent monotonic effect of `moDays` in `m1` can be obtained with lme4?

Comment: I'm following because I'm interested in the answer. I've been looking at a way of fitting monotonic effects in frequentist (G)LMMs for about a year now without any success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to do this with `lme4::lmer()`, but an alternative can be implemented with the package [glmmTMB](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glmmTMB/index.html)
.

I got the following answer by [Ben Bolker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/190277/ben-bolker) in the R mixed-models mailing list:

> "You can't constrain fixed-effect parameters in lme4::lmer (they are profiled out of the likelihood function, so they're not accessible to be constrained), but in glmmTMB you could do this"

```r
data("sleepstudy", package= "lme4")
ss <- within(sleepstudy, {
     Days <- factor(Days)
     contrasts(Days) <- MASS::contr.sdif
})
library(glmmTMB)
m1 <- glmmTMB(Reaction ~ Days + (1 | Subject), data = ss)
m2 <- update(m1,
             control = glmmTMBControl(
               optArgs = list(lower=c(-Inf, rep(0,9), rep(-Inf, 2)))))
```